# The url always the same i cant scrape

Tags: python, pandas, email, web-scraping, scrape

So i want to scrape this site https://www.hotelcareer.com/ i want the address, the job title, and the email address [Job title, address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/It0mE.png)[email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3E1MR.png)but there is a problem when i want to change a city or job title in the filter seciton the url is not change, is always the same like this : https://www.hotelcareer.com/jobs/job-offers . so i have a code.... but not working pls helpppp

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
l=[]

# URL = input("Please Enter URL of listing page = ")

try:
    driver.get("https://www.hotelcareer.com/jobs/job-offers")
except:
    print("May be, You entered wrong URL")
    driver.close()
    exit()
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//button[@title='Close']")))
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[@title='Close']").click()
except:
    pass
try:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 800)")
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//a[text()='50']")))
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[text()='50']").click()
    time.sleep(3)
except:
    pass
l=[]
while True:
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//ul[@class='resultlist']/li)[1]/descendant::a[@data-js-action]")))
    lenn = len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//ul[@class='resultlist']/li"))
    for i in range(lenn):
        try:
            link = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,f"(//ul[@class='resultlist']/li)[{i+1}]/descendant::a[@data-js-action]").get_attribute('href')
            print(link)
        except:
            link = ""
        l.append(link)
        print(i)
    try:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 800)")
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[@class='weiter']").click()
        time.sleep(3)
    except:
        break
l2 = []
print("Total Records = ",len(l))
for i in range(len(l)):
    d={}
    driver.get(str(l[i]))
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[@class='location']/a")))
    except:
        continue
    try:
        Title = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"(//h1)[1]").text
    except:
        Title = ""
    try:
        Address = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//span[@class='location']/a").text
    except:
        Address = ""
    try:
        Email = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[@id='email']").text
    except:
        Email = ""
    try:
        Website = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@id='contact_fields']/a[@target]").text
    except:
        Website = ""
    d['Job Title'] = Title
    d['Address'] = Address
    d['Email'] = Email
    d['Website'] = Website
    l2.append(d)
    df = pandas.DataFrame(l2)
    df.to_excel("Hotel.xlsx")
driver.close()
exit()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I have reviewed the code you provided and noticed that the second part, which is responsible for accessing each link and extracting the information, was not working correctly. Therefore, I decided to make some modifications. I introduced variables that will allow you to adjust the job title or city as needed. Additionally, I centralized the information extraction within the first loop you had established. I hope these changes prove useful.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas
import time
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
# driver.maximize_window()
l=[]

# URL = input("Please Enter URL of listing page = ")
job_title = 'Manager'
city = 'London'


try:
    driver.get("https://www.hotelcareer.com")
except:
    print("May be, You entered wrong URL")
    driver.close()
    exit()

WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='btnSearch_new']")))
city_box = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='input_ort']")
city_box.send_keys(city)
search_box = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='taetigkeiten']")
search_box.send_keys(job_title)
search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver,3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//button[@title='Close']")))
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[@title='Close']").click()
except:
    pass
try:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 800)")
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//a[text()='50']")))
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[text()='50']").click()
    time.sleep(1)
except:
    pass

while True:
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//ul[@class='resultlist']/li)[1]/descendant::a[@data-js-action]")))
    jobs = len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//ul[@class='resultlist']/li"))
    main_window_handle = driver.current_window_handle
    l2 = []
    for job in range(jobs):
        d = {}
        link = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,f"//ul[@class='resultlist']/li[{job+1}]")
        link.click()
        for window_handle in driver.window_handles:
            if window_handle != main_window_handle:
                driver.switch_to.window(window_handle)
                break

        WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='ycg_info_line']")))
        print("Title: %s" % driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='ycg_info_line']/h1").text)
        print("City: %s" % driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='inneroben']/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/span[1]").text)
        try:
            print("Email: %s" % driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='email']").text)
        except:
            print("Email: ")
        print("url %s" % driver.current_url)
        print()
        d['Job Title'] = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='ycg_info_line']/h1").text
        d['Address'] = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='inneroben']/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/span[1]").text
        try: 
            d['Email'] = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='email']").text
        except:
            d['Email'] = ''
        d['Website'] = driver.current_url
        l2.append(d)
        
        driver.close()
        driver.switch_to.window(main_window_handle)
    try:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 800)")
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[@class='weiter']").click()
        time.sleep(3)
    except:
        break

df = pandas.DataFrame(l2)
df.to_excel("Hotel.xlsx")
driver.close()
exit()
```

The output:

```
Title: Recruitung Managers for Hospitality in UK
City: London
Email: 
url https://www.hotelcareer.com/jobs/catererglobal-111880/recruitung-managers-for-hospitality-in-uk-3447079?rltr=dyn

Title: Marcomm Manager
City: London
Email: 
url https://www.hotelcareer.com/jobs/catererglobal-111880/marcomm-manager-3451751?rltr=dyn

Title: Butler Manager
City: London
Email: 
url https://www.hotelcareer.com/jobs/catererglobal-111880/butler-manager-3447785?rltr=dyn

Title: Hotel Manager- 4 Star Hotel( non branded) Dubai
City: London
Email: 
url https://www.hotelcareer.com/jobs/catererglobal-111880/hotel-manager-4-star-hotel-non-branded-dubai-3448403?rltr=dyn

Title: Manager Hygiene, Health, Safety and Sustainability
City: London
Email: 
url https://www.hotelcareer.com/jobs/catererglobal-111880/manager-hygiene-health-safety-and-sustainability-3449251?rltr=dyn

Title: Server/Dining Room Care Manager
City: London
Email: 
url https://www.hotelcareer.com/jobs/catererglobal-111880/server-dining-room-care-manager-3051990?rltr=dyn

Title: Learning Manager
City: London
Email: 
url https://www.hotelcareer.com/jobs/catererglobal-111880/learning-manager-3421620?rltr=dyn

Title: eCommerce/Digital Marketing Manager
City: London
Email: 
url https://www.hotelcareer.com/jobs/catererglobal-111880/ecommerce-digital-marketing-manager-3431043?rltr=dyn

Title: Assistant Manager - Gas Line Fittings
City: London
Email: 
url https://www.hotelcareer.com/jobs/catererglobal-111880/assistant-manager-gas-line-fittings-3453329?rltr=dyn

Title: Marketing PR Manager
City: London
Email: 
url https://www.hotelcareer.com/jobs/catererglobal-111880/marketing-pr-manager-3419440?rltr=dyn
```

In this case, the jobs did not have an email listed.